# What does "(Earnings Per Share) sen" mean in a shareholders' context?

Tags: stock-market

What does "**SEN**" / "**sen**" (possibly an abbreviation?) mean in a shareholders' context?

In particular, I am wondering how to interpret "**sen**" in the following context:

- "**Earnings Per Share (sen)**"

This can be encountered a lot, as a simple [google query "**Earnings Per Share (sen)**" shows](https://www.google.com/#q=%22Earnings+Per+Share+%28sen%29%22).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **"sen"** is no more than a 1/100 sub-unit of the (e.g.) currency Malaysian ringgit? Such a sub-unit is called "sen", and is etymologically related to the English word "cent".

It seems even more likely that **"sen"** in  **"Earnings Per Share (sen)"** refers to a 1/100 sub-unit of a currency, as [the google query **"Earnings Per Share (cents)"**](https://www.google.com/#q="Earnings+Per+Share+(cents)") yields many similar results.

But even if that would be the case, I think there can be more elaborate answers than mine, which also explains a bit more about the meaning of the words **"Earnings Per Share"**, in relation to numbers expressed in either **"cents"** or **"sen"**.

Comment: So is your question about currency names, or something else about earnings per share? If the latter, what is your specific question about earnings per share?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I only just discovered that **sen** is a currency, and the word **cent** indeed seems to be used in combination with the text string **Earnings Per Share** in an English context. But I could still have a lot too learn from an answer which would exactly explain what it in general means when you see some numbers in a shareholders' context specified as **Earnings Per Share**, and more particular (that would be an easy application then) expressed in **cents** or **sen**.